# How do I access a specific HTML element using C#?

Tags: c#, html, dom

I have a string containing HTML and I need to be able to access a specific element to get the text from it (the element has no id or class or name so regex is out of the question).

For example, lets say I needed to access: "/html/body/div/div[3]/div/table[0]/div/ul/li[12]/a/".

How could I go about doing this?

Comment: What do the numbers inside the brackets mean?

Comment: I think Html Agility Pack has something for that.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I'm guessing that `div[3]` means the 3rd div contained in that parent div, and so on.

Comment: @Robert Harvey: I assume you have never used firebug? When there are multiple tags of the same type at the same depth, the number is the index of occurance of that tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the HTML is well formatted, you can parse the HTML with an [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx)

Also as Maxim mentioned, the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) can probably do what you need.

[Here's a recent article from 4guysfromrolla](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020001935/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/011211-1.aspx) on parsing HTML with the HTML Agility Pack